# gtk text buffer error

Tags: textview, gtk, buffer

I want to print something to my textview `tv1` like this:

```
GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "test", -1);
gtk_text_view_set_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(tv1), buffer);
```

But the error:

At compiling: `warning: ‘buffer’ may be used uninitialized in this funct|
ion [-Wuninitialized]`

At running: `(gui:7280): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_buffer_set_text: assertion`GTK_|
IS_TEXT_BUFFER (buffer)' failed`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the compiler says, you're trying to use `buffer` before initializing it, which means the pointer isn't actually pointing at a GtkTextBuffer structure just yet.

I myself haven't used TextView's yet, but simply try adding `buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);` after declaring `*buffer`.